# Minecraft Linux Server | Start.sh problem

Tags: linux, server, minecraft

I have a Minecraft Server running on Linux.
I use to start the server, a start.sh file with following content:
(This content starts a screen session and the minecraft server)

`screen -S {ScreenSession} java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -jar spigot-1.18.1.jar`

If I use /restart ingame, the screen session will end and the server won't start. So I have to go into the Linux Server and start the Minecraft Server again.

**My question:**

How can I make it so, if I use /restart that the server will restart with a active screen session.

If have tried many things.
I hope someone can help me,
~Kitty Cat Craft

Comment: You can't. `/stop` will stop the server, and thus the screen.

Comment: then just restart

Comment: What do you mean with "start the server again" ? run the same command again ?

Comment: I mean if you use /restart, the server should restart but the screen session closes and the server won't start. So there needs to be a way, when i use /restart that the session restarts & the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple way to achieve what you want.

If you have lot of servers, you can use a quick bash script with an auto restart like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
   java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -jar spigot-1.18.1.jar --nogui
   sleep 5
done
```

When you will stop, it will wait 5 seconds then restart.

With this, you can use: `screen -dmS <screenName> sh myScript.sh` which will run the script into another screen. It's usefull when you run it from a script which run lot of server, like that:

```
screen -dmS srv1 sh srv1.sh
screen -dmS srv2 sh srv2.sh
screen -dmS srv3 sh srv3.sh
```

You can also, if you have only one server, just firstly use `screen -S screenName`. Then, when you are in the screen, run the script that restart automatically (the script that I gave at first).

Also, prefer use /stop than /restart, because spigot will try to find the script. And if it success, it will run a second time the same script, and so will have ghost process.

Comment: Thanks i will try.

Comment: So just replace all of the current folder with the bin thing and type the session things into the console, right?

Comment: No, you create a file with this content, then you run this file in a screen that you created

Comment: Error:

1. ./start.sh: line 1: $'\r': command not found
2. ./start.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
3. ./start.sh: line 7: `done'

Comment: It's because of how you saved the file. You seems to write it with Windows then upload to linux. I suggest you to remove the file, then create a new one with command line like `echo "" > myscript.sh`, then edit from windows (and you will have the good encoding)